# Running cronjob every 5 minutes but stopped after first execution?

Tags: python, cron

I have python script that checks if the server is up or down, and if it's down it sends out an email along with few system logs.

What I want is to keep checking for the server every 5 minutes, so I put the cronjob as follows:
*/5 * * * * /python/uptime.sh

So whenever the server's down, it sends an email. But I want the script to stop executing (sending more emails) after the first one.

Can anyone help me out with how to do this? 
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to put a condition in the script to check if the server is up, or you really want to delete the cronjob?

Comment: all the script does is check if the server is up or down. I just want to put a restriction on the cronjob, that if the script executes (in case the server goes down), then i should keep sending emails until server is back up. instead just one email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution is, you can set some Bash env variable `MONITORING=true` and let your python script to check that variable using `os.environ["MONITORING"]`. If that variable is `true` then check if the server is up or down else don't check anything. Once server down is found, set that variable to `false` from script like `os.environ["MONITORING"] = false`. So it won't send emails until you set that env variable again `true`.

Answer (score 0):

- write an empty `While True` script that runs forever (ex: "mailtrigger.py")
- run it with `-nohup mailtrigger.py` from shell in infinite loop
- once the server is down check if mailtrigger.py is running, if its
  not then terminate mailtrigger.py (`kill process id`)

your next iterations will not send mails since mailtrigger.py is not running.